# Putting returned S3 objects into an array

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, rxjs

Maybe I am overthinking this, but I puzzled by the issue I am facing.  I am currently using the JavaScript S3 SDK to pull some templates down from my buckets.  I am using a promise to return the results, however, the data that is returned is a bunch of objects because I am looping through a list of file paths where the objects are located. Because I am using a promise, it only returns one of the eighty or so returned objects.  So my solution is to place the returned objects in an array that I can pass as my returned data for my promise.  Is this something that RX would be applicable for and if so, what methods would be recommended?

```
var getTemplateParams = function (isoObj) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var params;
    var paths = isoObj.filePathArr.Contents;
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        params = {
            Bucket: isoObj.filePathArr.Name,
            Key: paths[i].Key,
            ResponseContentEncoding: 'utf-8',
            ResponseContentType: 'ReadableStream'
        }
        s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                data['isoId'] = isoObj.isoId;
                data['templateId'] = isoObj.templateId;
                data['siteName'] = isoObj.siteName;
                data['domain'] = isoObj.domain;
                data['mainEmail'] = isoObj.mainEmail;
                data['mainPhone'] = isoObj.mainPhone;
                data['Name'] = isoObj.filePathArr.Name;

                // The data that is returned needs to get put into an array.
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    };
})
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

In RxJS it would look something like this:

```
var getTemplateParams = function (isoObj) {

  //Turns this callback function into a function that returns a observable
  var getObjectObservable = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(s3.getObject);

  //Wrap the paths into an Observable
  return Rx.Observable.fromArray(isoObj.filePathArr.Contents)

           //Convert the paths in to param objects
           .map(function(path) {
             return {
               Bucket: isoObject.filePathArr.Name
               Key: path.Key,
               ResponseContentEncoding: 'utf-8',
               ResponseContentType: 'ReadableStream'
             };
           })
           //Have each request sent out to the server
           .flatMap(getObjectObservable, 
                    //Process each result
                    function(path, data) {

                //Don't fully understand why you are copying all the data 
                //from isoObject into the data object.

                data['isoId'] = isoObj.isoId;
                data['templateId'] = isoObj.templateId;
                data['siteName'] = isoObj.siteName;
                data['domain'] = isoObj.domain;
                data['mainEmail'] = isoObj.mainEmail;
                data['mainPhone'] = isoObj.mainPhone;
                data['Name'] = isoObj.filePathArr.Name;
                return data;
           })

           //Flatten all the results into an Array.
           .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do it like this.
Make each s3 request a promise and then use something Promise.all to resolve all the promises, which returns the results of the promises as an array
Just found this code I have used before. I use bluebird, but most promise frameworks should be able to do this

```
return Promise.all(photos.map(function(photo) {
  var params = 'bucketinfo'
  return s3.getSignedUrlAsync('getObject', params)
    .then(function(url) {
      return url;
    });
}));
```